# Dual Boot Windows 7 and Ubuntu with SSD and HDD

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, windows, ssd

So I have an Acer laptop that has both an HDD and SSD. I have been having trouble dual booting Ubuntu with Windows. For some reason Ubuntu does not recognize Windows and I do not want to wipe out windows hard drive... Ive done this 3 times already on accident ha(First time I lost Windows 8 but I hated it anyway). I was wondering if it was okay to keep windows on my hdd and just install ubuntu on my ssd(20 GB)?

Or in anyone has an alternate solution I am all ears.. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

1. Not to mess up with Windows while installing Ubuntu, do the partitions with Gparted THEN do a custom installation using the new partitions.
2. Grub2 should find the OS whatever disk they are on. Just make sure to install the grub to the 1st disk in the boot order.

Answer (score -1):

Since both the operating systems are on different hard drives, I think the BIOS will always check 1 disk before the other. And whichever OS it sees on that disk, it will boot into. One option to pick the OS at boot-up is to switch the boot-order when you boot. There is usually a small time-frame during boot-up in which you can press a key,for example, F11, but may be different, to enter boot options This should be displayed when you boot your machine.

boot...

Comment: Okay great.. I'm a noob trying to get experience with linux and I was not absolutely sure if it would mess up my computer or not. Thanks for the help!